# Persistent UI lag

Tags: nvidia, hardware, fan, logging

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.  I have a problem with lag in the user interface that has persisted for
a very long time.  I am of the opinion that it is a hardware issue, because it has lasted through
upgrades and multiple re-installations of the operating system.

The lag has recently gotten extremely bad.  I now need to pause between each keystroke when I type,
otherwise not all of the letters appear.  Each pause is more than 1 second long.

For reference, I have a system that I built myself.  I have a SuperMicro motherboard,
model MBD-H8DGI-F-0 with 2 Opteron CPU's, 32 MB of RAM, and a GeForce 9800 GT
video card.

I don't know if the problem is in the motherboard or the video card, so I don't know what
I need to replace.  I suspect the video card, simply because whenever I run any sort of
web browser (Chrome, Firefox, whatever), the fan in the video card speeds up instantly
and all my efforts to install a fan control have failed to exert any control over the
video card fan.

Is there some logging that I can look at or install to see what might be the cause of
this UI lag and/or fan speed issue?  I am hoping that I don't have to buy a whole new system.x

Comment: Is that 32MB or 32GB of RAM?

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo.  32 GB of RAM.